# Estimote beacon... didEnterInRegion doesn't call in Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, estimote

I need to work with an Estimote beacon.

When the app is in foreground `LocationMangaer` delegate method `didEnterInRegion` end `didExitRegion` are called properly, but I have a problem when the application is in background (with locked screen).

If I leave the device on a table and if I walk away with Estimate beacon, after a few meters the method `didExitRegion` is called.

When I approach to the device and enter in the region of the beacon (a few centimeters) the method `didEnterInRegion` or method `didDetermineState` aren't called never. If I unlock the screen, after a few seconds, the method `didEnterInRegion` are called.

This is my code:

```
NSUUID *beaconUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"MYUUID"];
    NSString *regionIdentifier = @"FuelPay";
    CLBeaconRegion *beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:beaconUUID identifier:regionIdentifier];
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
    beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = YES;

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;

    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:beaconRegion];
```

In the *Info.plist* I set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` property and I enable background mode (with "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories") in project capabilities.

What is wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Background monitoring is NOT the same as foreground monitoring. It may take a *while* (in the order of minutes also) to detect a beacon in background since the scanning ratio is reduced (otherwise your battery will drain too fast).

Try your tests waiting a little bit more, if `didExitRegion` is called it's counterpart `didEnterRegion` should be called too.

Anyway I assume that before you check the `didEnterRegion` you have previously performed an `exit`. I mean that if you launch your app while you are already within the range of a beacon (e.g. beacon and device in the same room) there is no way `didEnterRegion` will ever be called. So you can

- Trigger `didExitRegion` leaving the room
- Launch your app without any beacon in range

and then get close to your beacon again